# iOS7 Webview initial scroll position under Navigation bar

Tags: ios7

I have a webview which is scrolling as desired underneath a navigation bar.

However, when I first load the controller, the page loaded in the webview is scrolled so that it aligns with the top of the navigation bar.  When I scroll the web view, the correct inset is present at the top to sit correctly, it's just the initial position that is incorrect.

How can I get the initial position to be fully scrolled to the top, including the inset?

Comment: This is still an issue in 7.0.4 and none of the suggestions below fix it.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 14):

If you don't mind having an opaque navigation bar, then the simplest solution could be to do this in the view controller that contains your web view:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

The positioning of the frame will then adopt the same behavior as iOS6, magically!

Comment: Definitely works. However, what I would really like to see is the behaviour of a UITableViewController to be available in the UIViewController containing a UIWebView.

Answer (score 6):

Rick's answer is correct except the top value should be negative, this is what worked for me!

```
[self.webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-44, 0, 0, 0)];
[self.webView.scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-44, 0, 0, 0)];
[self.webView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

I used -44, if you don't have status bar on the top you should use -64.

Comment: The value must be positive. 44 or 64.

Comment: So many are asking how to suppress content under the status bar; this is what I needed to get a Web app to completely fill an iPad view port. I used -20 instead of -44, however.

Answer (score 5):

The way I solved this issue is with the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate callback. In the callback method for the web view I set do all the work to make the web view's scroll view look correct.

```
[webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];
[webView.scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];
[webView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it. The solution is pretty simple:

Go to the storyboard, select the view controller which contains your UIWebView and open the Attributes Inspector. Here, you'll see the title "Extend Edges", just uncheck the box "Under Top Bars" and I will work !

Hope this helps !

Comment: Not really what I'm asking for.  This reverts to pre iOS7 behaviour where the bounds of the webview begins at (0, navbarheight).

Answer (score 1):

use the below

```
CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGFloat navHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
applicationFrame.origin.y = navHeight + 4;
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the content offset of the webview's scrollview in `viewDidAppear:`, for example:

```
[self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -64) animated:NO];
```

Unfortunately, it has no effect if placed in `viewWillAppear:`, so when the view appears you will see a visible jump in the content as it shifts from underneath the navigation bar to its new location.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
- (void)loadView {
    ...

    _offsetSet = NO;
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    if (!_offsetSet) {
        [_webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.topLayoutGuide.length) animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    _offsetSet = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more general version of @Puran's answer, rather than hardwiring 44 or 64, get it from the topLayoutGuide. Also, if you load multiple times, you only need to change these values once:

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = self.myWebView.scrollView.contentInset;
if ( UIEdgeInsetsEqualToEdgeInsets(insets, UIEdgeInsetsZero)) {
    insets.top = -self.topLayoutGuide.length;
    [self.myWebView.scrollView setContentInset:insets];
    [self.myWebView.scrollView setScrollIndicatorInsets:insets];
    [self.myWebView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
}
```