# UIWebView inside UIPageViewController with UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I created a project with a `UIPageViewController` embedded in `UINavigationController` in the storyboard.
This pageController has 2 `UIViewController` with inside an instance of `UIWebViewController`. The problem is that the web view appear under the top bar.

Do you have any idea for solve this?

Note: 
I don't want to use `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` for solve this problem because I want that my web view will be visible under the `NavigationBar`

This is the PageViewController:

```
DataViewController *startingViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:0 storyboard:self.storyboard];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
self.dataSource = self.modelController;
```

This is the DataViewController:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"...My Html..." baseURL:nil];
[self.webView setDelegate:self];
```

The ModelController is the same of Apple Example Project

And this is the storyboard:
[image]

Comment: Don't you mean `UIWebView`? And show your code, what have you tried

Comment: @Ty_ I updated with the code

Comment: @Serluca if I understand this correctly you should adjust the `contentOffset` of the `UIWebView` so it isn't "under" the navigation bar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024031/ios7-webview-initial-scroll-position-under-navigation-bar

Comment: Set the contentOffset is not a good solution, I want solve this setting correctly the autoLayot

Answer (score 2):

If you wants to start the UIWebView under the Navigation Bar then there is one easier way to do .

Follow the below steps:

1. Select your ViewController in Storyboard.
2. In Attributes Inspector, there is one option in ViewController "**Under Top Bars**" uncheck this option.

After that your view will starts from the completion of the navigation Bar.

I think it will solve your problem..